# how to sort a queue using (just) another queue and some varibles, in less than O(n^2)?

Tags: sorting, queue

How can I sort a queue of size N, using just another queue of size N, and a finite number of variables?

the naïve implementation - finding the minimum of the queue and pushing it to the empty queue, then finding the new minimal and pushing it, etc. is O(n^2). is there a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: mmmm, if you can (or do) randomly access the queue, then, I am thinking, it's not a queue and maybe you should be using quicksort.

Comment: unfortunately, it's a queue. I can't use quicksort, since I can only use one other queue so (as far as I understand, qsort take more)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), which is O(n log n)